# UI-Router 1.X - How to test $transition service hooks with karma?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to migrate to ui-router 1.0.5 and have done most of the work but there are no examples of how to test new transition hooks that replaced `$stateChangeXXX` events listeners.

**Code before:**

`scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', this.hideSpinner_.bind(this));`

**After:**

`this.transitions_` is a `$transitions` service exposed by ui-router
`this.transitions_.onSuccess({}, this.hideSpinner_.bind(this));`

Before I was able to test it by using `scope.$broadcast($stateChangeSuccess)` and then `scope.$apply()`. This worked with ui-router 0.x:

```
expect(ctrl.loading).toBe(true);
expect(ctrl.showLoadingSpinner).toBe(true);

// when
scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess');
scope.$apply();

// then
expect(ctrl.loading).toBe(false);
expect(ctrl.showLoadingSpinner).toBe(false);
```

Any idea how to rewrite tests to work with new version of ui-router?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to test these hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same question. And I chose a stupid solution that is broadcasting the 'stateChangeStart' event in a onStart hook:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function($transition$){
  $scope.$broadcast('$myStateChangeStart', $transition$.to(), $transition$.params('to'), $transition$.from(), $transition$.params('from'), $transition$.options(), $transition$)
})
```

then I do not need to change so much of the legacy code, just handling some 'concurrency' logic.

Hope it makes sense. If you've got a good practice, pls tell me.

Comment: This is not what I've had in mind but as a temporary workaround should work to make tests pass. I'd not add it to actual code but rather register in test directly as it might impact performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I faced exactly the same problem migrating from ui-router 0.3.x to 1.0.5

## App

**Before :**

```
scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', someFunction);
```

**After :**

```
$transitions.onSuccess( {}, someFunction);
```

## Tests

**Before :**

```
scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess');
scope.$apply();
```

**After :**

I call directly the callback function with a mocked transition because I just want to test what the callback does (and here it only needs **trans.$to().name** and **trans.$from().name**) :

```
var mockTransition = {
    $to: function() { return {name: 'foo'}; },
    $from: function() { return {name: 'bar'}; }
};
service.someFunction(mockTransition);
$scope.$digest();
```

And in some places in my tests, I want to simulate the whole transition process so I do a real one, that way the events are properly called :

```
it('should handle transitions error properly when trying to make transition to an abstract state', function (done) {
    spyOn(console, 'error');
    spyOn(transitions, 'onError');

    transitions.onError({}, function(transition) {});

    $stateTest.transitionTo("c3.app.offre").then(function() {

    }, function() {
        expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(transitions.onError).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
    scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't really solve my problem. I need to be able to run callback function registered using i.e. transitions.onSuccess. In my case on successful state change some variables of a component are set.